# Are octal escape sequences more portable than hex ones for shell scripts

Tags: shell-script, shell, posix, utilities, portability

As part of a scheme for writing shell code that's capable of processing arbitrary data, I was looking for a way to convert null bytes to some other character. I found that `tr` requires arbitrary bytes to be escaped using octal. Some other non-GNU implementations of Unix utilities, which I now forget, also required octal escape sequences in place of the more common `\xHH` and non-printable characters in their output were expressed as octal escape sequences. The backing file for a loopback device in Linux can be found in `/sys/block/${LOOP_DEVICE}/loop/backing_file`; a non-printable character in the path of the backing file is expressed as the literal `\012`.

I had figured that octal escape sequences are the POSIX standard or the way it's been done since the Unix epoch and that `\xHH` is newer and less supported right when I learned about `tr` using them, but I am unsure if this suspicion is right. Will using `\OOO` over `\xHH` result in greater portability for my shell scripts/functions?

Comment: Portability in general means not using non-standad features and options. I guess that the use of non-standard options in shell scripts developed on Linux is the most important reason for a lack of portability.

Comment: @schily Which is why I'm asking if octal is more portable than hexadecimal.

Comment: It definitely is.

Answer (score 1):

What's supported depends on the utility.  For `tr` and `printf`, only octal sequences are supported by POSIX, and hexadecimal sequences are not.  Most modern Unix systems at least attempt to implement the POSIX standard, so relying on its features is generally safe.

If you want to see what POSIX supports, the [latest version](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) is online; you can look in the Shell and Utilities section to see information about each utility.